# Close vote review: First voted "Leave open" then realised it may be a duplicate

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Oh, I think I've messed this up, didn't I?

I came to review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533263/call-through-the-base-class-abstract-method) for closing because it was considered off-topic. Since I think the question itself is OK, I chose "Leave open".

Then I realised that this kind of question must have been asked before and [indeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734077/c-virtual-method-not-called-as-desired) it had. So I raised a close vote for being a duplicate.

Is this OK? If not, can it be fixed? By me?

Actually, though being a duplicate, I think the question is quite good. Maybe even better than the original. Should I upvote it then?

As far as I know questions that are closed for being off-topic are eventually deleted. Duplicates may be kept active because others may find the duplicate still helpful. Is this correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't worry, this happens from time to time and it's one of the reasons the system requires *three* Leave Open votes from the review queue to remove the question from the queue. You did the right thing by going back to the question and voting to close it as a duplicate. The next reviewers, who might disagree (as you did) with the question being off-topic, will now see that somebody voted to close as a duplicate, which they might agree with. And they don't even have to search for the duplicate, because you already did.

> Actually, though being a duplicate, I think the question is quite good. Maybe even better than the original. Should I upvote it then?

Yes, you may. Good duplicates serve as [signposts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32311/295232), and while you should definitely compare the quality of the *questions*, the quality of the *answers* matters more. Even if the new question is 'better', and people searching in Google will hit it more often, if it's closed as a duplicate, anonymous users (90% of the traffic) are [*automatically* redirected to the duplicate target](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125220/295232), where they will find the better answers.